# what is the name of foreign key constraint generated by laravel migration

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have created news table with CreateNewsTable migratin. the CreateNewsTable migration codes is:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateNewsTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->string('author');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('title_image_path');
        $table->string('summary');
        $table->text('body');
        $table->bigInteger('timestamp');
        $table->boolean('published');

        $table->primary(['author', 'title', 'timestamp']);
        $table->foreign('author')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('news');
}
}
```

Now I want to remove foreign key constraint but I don not know the name of foreign key constraint.
please help me.thanks for your answer in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find foreign keys in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` in the table `KEY_COLUMN_USAGE`

For example, to find foreign keys for the table `news`:

`SELECT * FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE where TABLE_NAME = 'news';`

The name of the foreign key is in a column named `CONSTRAINT_NAME`

Comment: Yottatron, thanks for quick and useful answer.my problem solved.